# Right Hand Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I was told to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^2}$$

I know that the limit at 0 is equal to one since $0^0 = 1$, but I don't know what the correct way to do a RHL/LHL is. Do I just sub in a value > 0?

Comment: Yes $0^0$ is $1$, but the $x^y$ operation is **not continuous there**, so the limit of the power will not necessarily equal the power of the limits. You need something else.

Comment: @HenningMakholm $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek: No, it's not. $a^0=1$ by definition, _in every unital ring_, _for every $a$_.

Comment: Maybe $a^0=1$ in *your* definitions, but this is definitely not the way everyone does it. Personally, I've never heard of that convention, and I don't seem to be the only one. Anyways, whether or not $0^0$ equals $1$, it is irrelevant to the limit the OP is trying to evaluate

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek That's a long standing debate. I'm on Henning's side about $0^0=1$; however this tells nothing at all when a limit is computed. Note that whoever refuses $0^0=1$ should also refuse $0\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: @egreg please elaborate on $0\cdot 0=0$ implying $0^0=1$; I'd be quite interested to see that!

Comment: There have been many discussions about $0^0$ on this site. See [Zero to the zero power - is $0^0=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11150) and its long list of linked threads. As for the exponentiation, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105203) by Marc van Leeuwen also worths a read.

Comment: @egreg I can't follow your implication. I just follow the definition of $x^y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which is $\exp(y\ln(x))$

Comment: This is a "tree falls in the forest" problem. There are two distinct operations, integer exponentiation and real exponentiation. The former is defined for every monoid by $a^0=1, a^{n+1}=a^n\cdot a$ (and if an inverse exists, $a^{-n}=(a^{-1})^n$). The latter is defined specifically for Reals, complexes etc. by $x^y=\exp(y\log x)$. It's unfortunate that we use the same notation for both operations, but they're not the same. In integer exponentiation $0^0=1$. In real exponentiation $0^0$ is an undefined indeterminate form.

Comment: I like to take it further - though this is debatable - and say that there is also a distinction between the integer 0 and the real 0. We can determine which exponentiation we mean by looking at which exponent we mean. If the exponent is the integer 0, $0^0=1$. If the exponent is the real 0, $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld The real exponentiation with base $0$ is undefined; it's that easy! `;-)`

Comment: $z^z$ is indeterminate at the origin. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732550/plotting-y-x1-y/2240926#2240926

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whether or not you define $0^0=1$, this has no relevance for the problem at hand, because you are *not* computing $0^0$, but a limit.

Note that the power $a^x$ (where $x$ is allowed to take any real value) can only sensibly be defined for $a>0$, so the equality
$$
a^x=\exp(x\log a)
$$
(natural logarithm and standard exponential function) holds.

One *could* also define $0^x=0$ (for $x>0$), but it would only be marginally useful. And it turns out that the two variable function
$$
f(x,y)=x^y
$$
defined for $x>0$ and any $y$ has no limit for $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

This explained, you should always treat limits of the form
$$
\lim_{x\to c}f(x)^{g(x)}
$$
(two-sided or one-sided) with the following strategy:

1. compute $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\log f(x)$
2. if the limit in 1 exists and is finite, say $l$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^l$
3. if the limit in 1 exists and is $\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)^{g(x)}=\infty$
4. if the limit in 1 exists and is $-\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)^{g(x)}=0$
5. if the limit in 1 does not exist, then neither the original limit exists.

In this case,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2\log x=0
$$
which is a basic limit, so indeed
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{x^2}=e^0=1
$$

Comment: I wish people really take note of your opening sentence. I could see a lot of fuss on defining $0^{0}$ in comments to other answer which is totally irrelevant here. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Jaideep's and egrep's solutions are correct. But we want to dispute a claim in a comment that $(=0)^{=0}$  is well defined. I think we all have a duty to find out the truth for the benefit of everyone.

Comment: @HocNgo There's no inherent truth in the matter, it's a question of conventions. Either one defines $0^0$ or one doesn't. The convention that I follow is that $0^0 = 1$. Always. Except when it isn't.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck But that is an entirely different matter. Whether a function is defined at a point is a different question than whether the limit of the function at that point exists.

Comment: @DanielFischer The idea that functions are necessarily continuous is hard to eradicate

Answer (score 4):

Let $$A=\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^2}$$

Now take logarithm both the sides.

$$\ln A= \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^2 \ln x$$

Now you can use L'Hopitals rule :

$$\ln A = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

$$\ln A= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-2}{x^3}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} -\frac{x^2}{2} =0$$

$$\ln A =0 \implies A=1$$

Comment: @HenningMakholm (=0)^{(=0)} Isn't defined! Your comment seems to say that it is defined.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Is it okay now, since it has nothing to do, I have removed now.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, can you point to a reference where $0^0$ is defined? Note that  if $n$ is a positive integer, $0^n$ is well defined and is equal to $0$. But $0^0$ can be written as $0^{n-n}$, or $0^n/0^n$, and division by zero is always undefined.

Comment: @HocNgo: $a^0=1$ is part of the **definition** of exponentiation _for every_ $a$, _in every unital ring_. Your reasoning would lead to denying that $0^1$ is defined because $0^2/0^1$ divides by zero.

Comment: @HocNgo: On the other hand, $a^{x-y}=a^{x}/a^y$ is not a definition, but a _property_ that exponentiation has _under certain conditions_. Among those conditions is that $a^x$ and $a^y$ are both defined and that one can divide by $a^y$

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I agree that my reasoning is flawed when the base is 0. But I still need to see a reference to $0^0$ being a defined value. BTW, how do you apply the L'Hopital's rule in your last expression? I know the limit is zero but the RHS is of the form $0\cdot\infty.$

Comment: @HocNgo By converting it into a fraction of $\infty / \infty $ we can use L'Hopitals rule. See my edit.

Comment: @HocNgo: The fundamental definition of $x^y$ is for $y\in\mathbb N_0$ by the recursion equations $$ x^0 =1 \qquad\qquad x^{y+1} = x^y\cdot x $$ This notion is later _extended_ to larger domains for $y$ by definitions that involve limits, but this _extension_ does not make the values fixed by the _original_ definition go away. And the original definition has nothing do do with limits.

Comment: @HenningMakholm we're talking about $x^y$ where $x,y\in\Bbb R$ now though, so in that case I guess we agree that we shouldn't assume $0^0=1$. Exponentiation is defined differently when the exponent is a real number rather than a non-negative integer

Comment: @Jaideep, thanks for your edit. I asked this question because what I learned from 45 years ago was that L'Hopital's rule applies to the $0/0$ form only and we students at the time were not allowed to apply to the $\infty/\infty$ form. We had to resort to a change variable to $t=1/x$. So I now learn something new today.

Comment: @vrugtehagel: If you don't agree that $0$ is a non-negative integer, then I cannot help you here.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't agree to that. Of course, $0$ is a non-negative integer. I'm saying you cannot use that definition for real numbers because it's being defined differently. Sure, in most cases, those definitions coincide, but I don't think this is the case where $x=y=0$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel: If you agree that $0$ is a non-negative integer, and that $0^0$ is something raised to $0$, then you must also agree that $0^0$ is something raised to a non-negative integer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I remember learning in the algebra class that $x^0 = 1$ is a convention for all numbers $x$ because it makes the quotient rule consistent. Of course, algebra was taught before calculus and we never considered $0^0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Note $x^y$ is first defined for integer $y$ and is later extended by analytic continuation of $y$ to real or complex $y$. If $0^0$ is in deed well defined and has a finite limit, the limiting form $(\to 0)^{(\to 0)}$ must then be well defined as well, simply based on analytic continuation. So if there are examples where $(\to 0)^{(\to 0)}$ is not 1, then I think $0^0$ is not well defined.

Comment: Based on wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form, $0^0$ is one of the indeterminate forms. So $(exact\, 0)^{(exact\, 0)}$ is indeed undefined.

Comment: @HocNgo: "Indeterminate form" is not the same as "undefined". Indeterminate form means that the _limit_ of $f(g(x),h(x))$ cannot be computed by knowing the limits of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ separately; it has nothing at all to do with whether the value of $f$ itself is defined at a particular point.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: If $(=0)^{(= 0)}$ were 1, then the function $f(x,y)=x^y$ could be analytically continued to $(0,0)$ easily, resulting in $f$ being continuous at $(0,0)$. For any continuous function $g(x)$, the limit at $x_0$ is equal to $g(x_0).$ So, in the case of $f(x) = x^{x^2}$, we simply invoke the continuity property to conclude $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 1$ without going through the manipulations shown in Jaideep's and egreg's solutions.

Comment: @HocNgo: The function $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, which invalidates every argument that assumes it is. And the extension of $x^y$ from integer $y$ to real $y$ is _not_ by analytic continuation; you can't even use analytic continuation for a function that is not already defined on an open set (or at least a set with an accumulation point).